# Why doesn't the scrollTo event work when added within a delay?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, dom-events, settimeout

Even if I try
setTimeout(e.target.scrollTo({ top: 0, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' }), 50000);

The ScrollTo doesn't respect the time.

Hey everyone, I'm trying to make a scroll within setTimeout to create a delay, but I'm having trouble with it. In my implementation, it's just saying that some parameters are missing, and even if I add them, it still doesn't work!

But I have a function and the `e` parameter to scroll.

```
const updateKanbanOnScrollBottom = (params, e) => {
   setTimeout(() => {
       e.target.scrollTo({ 
           top: e.target.scrollHeight - 2000, 
           left: 0, 
           behavior: 'smooth' 
       });
   }, 5000, e);
};
```

But this is not working, what should I Do? Even if I try this, directly

```
setTimeout(e.target.scrollTo({ 
    top: 0, 
    left: 0, 
    behavior: 'smooth' 
}), 50000);
```

If you can help me, I would really appreciate it, but basically, I need a scroll with a delay.

Comment: you are specifying `e.target.scrollHeight - 2000` which could result in no scrolling - what is the 2000px subtraction for?

Comment: This is not the point, my 
"e.target.scrollTo({ top: e.target.scrollHeight - 2000, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' }); "
works perfect with no delay... But I need to add some delay, but i don't know how.

Comment: maybe try storing `e.target` in a variable before time out, and use that variable like `element.scrollTo`

Comment: Pass in `e.target` instead of `e` as your third argument, then in the callback receive the `target` as argument directly. It's possible the target has changed during the timeout.

Comment: I pass the e.target and It worked